# Python3: Building dictionary from .fasta - "strange" printout for value

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, fasta

I am parsing a .fasta-File containing one big sequence into python by using:

```
for rec in SeqIO.parse(faFile, "fasta"):
    identifier=(rec.id)
    sequence=(rec.seq)
```

Then, I am building a dictionary:

```
d={identifier:sequence}
```

When printing sequence only, I get the following result:

```
CAGCCAGATGGGGGGAGGGGTGAGCGCTCTCCCGCTCAAAACCTCCAGCACTTT...CAT
```

**Note: All letters are printed, I made dots to shorten this**

When printing the dictionary, I get:

```
{'NC_003047.1': Seq('CAGCCAGATGGGGGGAGGGGTGAGCGCTCTCCCGCTCAAAACCTCCAGCACTTT...CAT', SingleLetterAlphabet())}
```

Where does the "Seq" and the SingleLetter alphabet come from?

Desired result would be:

```
{'NC_003047.1':'CAGCCAGATGGGGGGAGGGGTGAGCGCTCTCCCGCTCAAAACCTCCAGCACTTT...CAT'}
```

## Update1:

following the link in the comments, I tried

```
input_file=open(faFile)
d=SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(faFile,"fasta"))
```

resulting in:

```
{'NC_003047.1': SeqRecord(seq=Seq('CAGCCAGATGGGGGGAGGGGTGAGCGCTCTCCCGCTCAAAACCTCCAGCACTTT...CAT', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='NC_003047.1', name='NC_003047.1', description='NC_003047.1 Sinorhizobium meliloti 1021 chromosome, complete genome', dbxrefs=[])}
```

So, sadly, this does not help :(

Thanks in advance for your time and effort :)

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698807/parse-fasta-sequence-to-the-dictionary

Comment: this may solve my problem, but I still would like to know, where this seq and singleletteralphabet info come from ^^"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SeqIO` doesn't return a string, it returns an object. When you print it, you print the object's string representation, which in this case is not just the data contained in (some attribute of) the object.

(Some objects are designed so that printing the object will print just the data inside it. This depends on how the library is put together and how the programmer designed its `__str__()` method. This is probably not useful for you at this point, but might help you understand other related resources you find if you pursue this further.)

I'm not familiar with `SeqIO` but quick googling suggests you probably want

```
d={identifier: sequence.seq}
```

to put just the SeqIO object's `seq` attribute as the value for this identifier.

Comment: thank you for this info :) I also googled around with SeqIO but did not encounter this background info :)

Comment: trying your suggestions leads to an error, "Seq object as no attribute seq". I tried to do this: for rec in SeqIO.parse(faFile,"fasta"):
    d={rec.id:rec.seq}  and this gave me the "fail output" I already did not understand in the beginning. I hoped, that rec.seq would then mean, not to print the whole string representation, but only the sequence, but somehow not :/

Comment: Hmmm, looking further into the doco, I guess `sequence.seq.seq` or `sequence.seq.seq.tostring()` or something like that. The interface doesn't seem to be designed for what you are doing really.